# For loop not iterating over items in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

#### Where I'm At

I'm looking to loop over items in an array that relates to buttons' classes and their corresponding value for a form for a silent auction.

When a person makes a bid, they will see the latest bid and then clicking one of the buttons of six predefined values `$10, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500` will take that value, add it to the `.current__amount` then change the `html()` to show the `.new__amount`

#### Problem

Right now, clicking one of the six buttons does not add the value to the `.new__amount` it just stays as the placeholder text **"tk-amount"** So, I'm wondering if this is an issue of scope or if my for loop construction is off?

#### scripts.js

```
/*-------------------------------------
STEP ONE: PLACE BID
--------------------------------------*/

// Bid Options
var buttons = [
    { class: "buttonOne", value: 10 },
    { class: "buttonTwo", value: 25 },
    { class: "buttonThree", value: 50 },
    { class: "buttonFour", value: 100 },
    { class: "buttonFive", value: 250 },
    { class: "buttonSix", value: 500 }
]

$(".button__form").on('click', function(){
    var btnSelected = $(this).hasClass("is-selected");
    var sectionOneCompleted = $(".check--one").hasClass("is-completed");

    if (btnSelected) {
        $(this).removeClass("is-selected");
        $(".check--one").css("color", "#ccc");
    } else {
        $(".button__form").removeClass("is-selected");
        $(this).addClass("is-selected");
        $(".check--one").css("color", "#ffdc00");
    }
});

    /*-------------------------------------
    API: SHEETSU
    --------------------------------------*/

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://sheetsu.com/apis/4a8eceba",
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json"
    }).then(function(spreadsheet) {


        // Print current bid
        var currentBid = parseInt(spreadsheet.result.pop().Bids);
        $(".current__amount").html(currentBid);

        // Any of the form buttons
        var $btnForm = $(".button__form");

        for(i = 0; i < buttons.length ; i++){
            if ($btnForm.hasClass(buttons[i].class)){
                var newBid = $(".new__amount").html("$" + (currentBid + buttons[i].value));
                console.log(newBid);
            }
        }
    });
```

I also tried this in place of the for loop with little success.

```
        buttons.forEach(function(button) {
            if ($btnForm.hasClass(button.class)){
              var newBid = $(".new__amount").html("$" + (currentBid + button.value));
              console.log(newBid);
            }
```

#### index.html

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button class="button__form button__one">$10</button>
    <button class="button__form button__two">$25</button>
    <button class="button__form button__three">$50</button>
    <button class="button__form button__four">$100</button>
    <button class="button__form button__five">$250</button>
    <button class="button__form button__six">$500</button>
</div><!-- /.buttons -->



<div class="bids__amounts">
    <div class="bids__amount bids__current">
        <p class="bids__note">The current bid is</p>
        <h4 class="current__amount">tk-amount</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="bids__amount bids__new">
        <p class="bids__note">Your bid will be</p>
        <h4 class="new__amount">tk-amount</h4>
    </div><!-- /.bids__amount -->
</div><!-- /.bids__amounts -->
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bqqLxvb9/

Comment: First of alll ascertain for sure that the code is reaching inside that condition in your loop. Stick a `console.log` in there or something. Never assume a line of code is running.

Comment: My understanding is that it's not, I've console.log(newBid) but that has not turned up anything in the console, so I'm a little confused about that.

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting console errors? `class` is a reserved word but I notice you're declaring it as a literal property name in your object. Use `{'class':`, not `{class` - similarly when calling it: `['class']` rather than dog syntax `.class`

Comment: To avoid problems down the road avoid using `class`, since this is a reserved word. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Reserved_keywords_as_of_ECMAScript_6

Comment: Consider using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), this would warn you about using `class` aswell as your missing variable declarations.

Comment: Also, just in case you don't know, be sure to make use of the debugger tools in your IDE or browser so you can place breakpoints and step through to see exactly where things are going awry.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do with loop and button array, but if you just want to see the bids against highest and current, this might help : http://jsfiddle.net/bqqLxvb9/1/

Comment: @DinoMyte That's kind of what I'm looking for the data has to be grabbed from a Google Spreadsheet after making an AJAX call to the SheetsU API. I'm looking to make take the number / last bid from `.current__amount` and add the value of the bid amount to the `.new__amount`.

Answer (score 0):

None of your buttons has the classes you're defining in your javascript:

JavaScript

```
var buttons = [
    { class: "buttonOne", value: 10 },
    { class: "buttonTwo", value: 25 },
    { class: "buttonThree", value: 50 },
    { class: "buttonFour", value: 100 },
    { class: "buttonFive", value: 250 },
    { class: "buttonSix", value: 500 }
]
```

HTML

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button class="button__form button__one">$10</button>
    <button class="button__form button__two">$25</button>
    <button class="button__form button__three">$50</button>
    <button class="button__form button__four">$100</button>
    <button class="button__form button__five">$250</button>
    <button class="button__form button__six">$500</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Just fixed that. Still having problems though